# How to use add_product function for variations in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to add product variations using the add_product() function from woocommerce.

But everytime I add the variation product. It just adds the parent product and not the variation.

```
$product_id = 40;
$variation_id = 42;
$quantity = 1;
$variation_name = color;
$variation_option = red;

$args = array(
    'attribute_'.$variation_name => $variation_option,
);

$order = wc_create_order();
$order->add_product( get_product( $product_id ), $quantity, $args );
```

I also have tried this which also doesn't work

```
$order->add_product( get_product( $variation_id ), $quantity, $args );
```

I have doubled checked the variation id, attribute, name and option.

Comment: have you tried `$order->add_product( wc_get_product( $variation_id ), $quantity, $args );`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think something wrong pass args parameter try this

```
$product_id = 132;
$quantity = 1;

$args = array( 
 'variation' => array( 'attribute_color' => 'red'),
); 

$order = wc_create_order();
$order->add_product( get_product( $product_id ), $quantity, $args );
//$order->set_total( 15.50 ); // set total amount for paid order including tax, fees etc.
```

Answer (score 0):

> **Edited in 2022**

1 - The `get_product()` function is  deprecated and the `wc_get_product()`function should be used.

2 - To calculate the final price, `calculate_totals()` function should be used to set the paid price.

UPDATE CODE :

Create a manual WooCommerce order:

```
$args = array(
    'status' => 'wc-completed', // The type of product status is up to you
    'customer_id' => 1, // user ID
    'customer_note' => null,
    'parent' => null,
    'created_via' => null,
    'cart_hash' => null,
);
$order = wc_create_order($args);
```

and set a desired product to order.

And we use the function `wc_downloadable_product_permissions()` to set the access of product download files.

```
$product_id = 100;
$quantity = 1;
$args = array(
    'name' => "",
    'tax_class' => "",
    'product_id' => 100,
    'variation_id' => "",
    'variation' => "",
    'subtotal' => 0,
    'total' => 0, // If you want the price of the selected product, remove it
    'quantity' => 1,
);

$order->add_product( wc_get_product( $product_id ), $quantity, $args );

$order->calculate_totals(); // To calculate the final price paid

wc_downloadable_product_permissions($order->get_id(), true); //Set product download access for order
```